# OL3: Is it possible adding different layers with different projections in one map using openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I want to add two different layers in one map. A is using `EPSG:4326` projection, while B is using `EPSG:3857` projection. When I tried this with *`openlayers3`*, some error come out.
I can't find function like setProjection in ol.View, it seems that `openlayers3` do not support this action.

---

But when i use Cesium, Cesium support this.
What can i do if i have to do this with `openlayers3`?

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers 3 can reproject vector data sources without any problem. But since you mention Cesium, I guess you are asking about raster sources. Raster reprojection is currently not possible, but it is a planned feature.